# How to use QCOMPARE Macro to compare events

Tags: qt, qt4, qtestlib

I have MyWindow class which pops up a blank window, which accepts a mouse click, I need to unit test the mouse click event

**Code snippet:**

```
void TestGui::testGUI_data()
{
  QTest::addColumn<QTestEventList>("events");
  QTest::addColumn<QTestEventList>("expected");

  Mywindow mywindow;
  QSize editWidgetSize = mywindow.size();
  QPoint clickPoint(editWidgetSize.rwidth()-2, editWidgetSize.rheight()-2);

  QTestEventList events, expected;
  events.addMouseClick( Qt::LeftButton, 0, clickPoint);
  expected.addMouseClick( Qt::LeftButton, 0, clickPoint);
  QTest::newRow("mouseclick") << events << expected ;
}

void TestGui::testGUI()
{
  QFETCH(QTestEventList, events);
  QFETCH(QTestEventList, expected);

  Mywindow mywindow;
  mywindow.show();

  events.simulate(&mywindow);
  QCOMPARE(events, expected); } // prints FAIL!  : TestGui::testGUI(mouseclick) Compared values are not the same
  ...
}
```

How to test the mouse click on `mywindow`. is there any better approach to unit test mouse events?

Thanks,
vels

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on QTest namespace documentation. There is QTest::mouseClick function which allows you to emulate mouse click on the given position of your widget (there is even no necessity to show the widget).

As far as I remember QCOMPARE uses "operator==" for the arguments given and if it returns false then it tries to print it using "QTest::toString<T>(const T& t)" function. If there is no implementation for a type of QCOMPARE arguments then it will just print that values are different. Again take a look on the QTest namespace documentation for details how to reimplement "QTest::toString<T> (const T& t)" for the type you need.